# Why would Visual Studio watches context fail in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, visual-studio-2015

I use visual studio 2015 with an ASP.NET website written in C#.  When I debug the site by attaching to the w3wp process and try to add a watch, it normally works for simple variables, but as soon as I try to use LINQ methods (not involving lambda), for example simply calling ToList() on a variable (when I know the method exist on the variable), the watch window returns an error message like:

```
    statistics.ToList() error CS1061: 'IGrouping<<>f__AnonymousType8<int, string, string>, PerformanceMetricStatistic>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<<>f__AnonymousType8<int, string, string>, PerformanceMetricStatistic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Or if I try to use something really simple like Convert.ToDecimal(val) I get:

```
    Convert.ToDecimal(aggregate.Average)    error CS0103: The name 'Convert' does not exist in the current context
```

I get the same exact error if I try the same code in the Immediate Window.

Comment: It's `System.Convert`

Comment: Does that code compile in a .cs file with no usings at the top?

Comment: Everything compiles.  System.Convert works, but calling an extension method like .ToList() doesn't.

Comment: How is your `statistics` formed? : testing with: `var x = new[] {new {id = 1}, new { id = 1 }, new { id = 2 }, new { id = 3 } };var g = x.GroupBy(c => c);` gives a valid result in my watch window. But the type of `g`is `System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`